# Are there different duties when living in a non-Islamic country?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim-countries, politics

If I'm not living in an Islamic country, do I have different duties and efforts to realize than in an Islamic country?

Comment: Yes, for examples, you don't find lot of Mosques, it's harder to find halal food (non-vegetarian), etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, Muslim duties and efforts should not change by country. Religious obligations are only conditioned by necessity and ability.

In other words what you "should do" doesn't change but what you "can do" does in fact vary according to your location.

In a non-Muslim country you should be a good example because you are the image the people will get on Islam and Muslims

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question does not make sense.  Each Muslim has to follow Prophet Muhammad(sw) and the Qur'aan.  Both of these are same in every corner of the world.

One more thing to think about:  our God doesn't want to send us to hell.  Allah always love us more than anyone.  Ask him for forgiveness if you can't do you duties.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you have more duties than those living in the muslim counties. The duty is to connect yourself to ALLAH (The Glorified) and make a sincere effort to connect other muslims (who are distracted for some reason) and non-muslims to ALLAH (The Glorified). Are you ready for that? May ALLAH (The Glorified) Make it easy for you.